# Google Sheets attendance tracking formula

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I have an attendance sheet that lists [A] names of participants, and [B] dates of attendance . Participants may have 1 or more dates of attendance. It is a running list that will be added to daily.

In a second sheet, I'm using Unique in [A] to pull all the names from the first sheet. Across the top row I am using Transpose / Unique to pull all the dates anyone attended.
[Side by side of sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kM84.png)

What I can't figure out is the formula to go in each checkboxes' cell. It would need to check Sheet 1 for both that name and that matching date. If that record exists in sheet 1, check the box (True). If not, leave box unchecked.

I imagine it involves some form of Index / Match or possibly vLookup/hLookup but I struggle mightily with these and could use some help. Thank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula to populate the table on Sheet 2, then Insert -> Checkbox on the whole range to convert them into checkboxes:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP((A2:A5&B1:E1),ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A2:A10&Sheet1!B2:B10),1,FALSE)),0)<>0,TRUE,FALSE))
```

In the sample image, this should look like this:

[image]

[image]

References:

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Comment: That nailed it! Thank you for that!   (Now if you know why I got 2 downvotes that would be great to know too.  It's my first post I'm assuming I didn't "research" enough but I was stuck and not even sure what functions to research any further.)

Comment: If Carlos' answer solved your issue, please be sure to checkmark it as the "correct" answer to help others with a similar question.